# Protractor Browser Instance Crash

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Our UI suite has begun failing in Chrome on login. Our original thought was that it was caused by updating to Chrome 79, since they happened around the same time. Running in Firefox still works.
Currently we have something like this:

`await this.loginButton.click()`

However, about six months ago the promise began not returning. Taking out the await:

`this.loginButton.click()`

And this causes a `StaleElementReferenceError`. Using browser actions actually worked even if it's a little ugly:

```
await browser.actions().mouseMove(this.loginButton).perform();
browser.actions().click().perform();
```

But protractor's browser instance becomes unresponsive immediately after clicking the login button. Cannot use `frameSwap()`, `get()`, or even restart the instance using `browser.restart()`. The execution simply freezes and those methods never return.

Using a cookie to log in and circumventing the actual login page does not cause the browser instance to crash. This makes it seem like the login action is causing the crash, but I have no idea how this could occur.

At the same time we began seeing this problem, we also began seeing a `NoSuchWindowError` on browser waits:

`await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(targetElement)`

I suspect that they are related but internet searches turned up nothing.

Chrome: 79-80

Protractor: 5.4.2

webdriver-manager 12.1.7

Thank you so much for your help ahead of time.

Comment: Maybe try like [this](https://www.edureka.co/community/9280/error-stale-element-reference-element-attached-page-document) for `StaleElementReferenceError` and see if anything changes

Comment: Unfortunately, even if that worked, the browser instance would still be unresponsive. Like I said, I was able to work around the login button exception with browser actions, but the browser instance crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, with the release of Chrome 83 this issue no longer occurs.